# PowerShell - Create folder with tomorrow's date as the name, but skip weekends

Tags: date, powershell, directory

Every evening I need to run a batch file to convert some txt files into PDF and move them into a folder with the current day's date as the folder name. That's the easy part.

The harder part is, as part of the same batch file, I also need to create a folder with the following day's date as the folder name but I need to skip weekends.  So if I run the script on a Friday, I need it to automatically name the folder with Monday's date instead of Saturday's.

My script so far looks like this:

```
$tomorrow = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(+1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

$folder = "S:\DailyReports\" + "$tomorrow"

New-Item -Path $tomorrow -ItemType directory

$today = (Get-Date -Format dd-MM-yyyy)

$folder = "S:\DailyReports\" + "$Today"

New-Item -Path $folder -ItemType directory
```

This works absolutely fine for Monday-Thursday evenings, but if I were to run this on a Friday evening, it'll simply create a folder with Saturday's date instead of Monday's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by simply checking if today is Friday, and adding three days if it is Friday.  If it's not Friday, then just add one day as your code already does.

```
if((get-date).DayOfWeek -eq 'Friday'){

    $tomorrow = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(+3).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

} else {

    $tomorrow = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(+1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

}
```

Comment: simple, yet genius! Thank you so much, Tony, it worked a treat!